# How to put line spacing with a certain length (kind of manually)

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I need to write a entire document with line spacing equals 1.5 cm. I've searched about it and found that there is three kinds of spacing: single, double and 1.5, but I need my document to be EXACTLY 1.5 cm (centimeters!). How do I do that? Is there some relation between "LaTeX spacing" and "centimeters"? I mean, for example,
A 1.5 spacing is approximatedly x cm (What is the value of x?)

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

If this is LaTeX, try `\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5cm}` anywhere after `\begin{document}`; if Plain or thereabouts, type `\baselineskip=1.5cm` directly.

Comment: Do I put this after \begin{document} or at the preamble? Sorry, I'm new in LaTeX...

Comment: You can do it anywhere in the document; but for consistency's sake, do it in the preamble to make it global.

Comment: @erreka no `\begin{document}` does `\normalsize` which will reset the baselineskip (unless `\normalsize` is also redefined to use 1.5cm space) so after `\begin{document}` is easier.

Comment: I stand corrected. I'll edit my answer accordingly.